# create dropdown list from database in laravel via controller

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a dropdown from the database, but the result is still an object. how to make the dropdown filled with an array of tables

my controller

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $complain = new Complain();
        $data = $complain->findData($id);

        $user = User::select('id','name')->where('role_id', '=', 3, 'and')->where('type_id', '=', 3)->get();

        $html = '<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ticket">No Ticket:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ticket" id="editTicket" value="' . $data->ticket . '" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="complain">Complain Detail:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="complain" id="editComplain" disabled>' . $data->complain . '
                    </textarea>
                </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="editName" value="' . $data->name . '" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="kartu">Card Number:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kartu" id="editKartu" value="' . $data->kartu . '" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pic_id">Assign To:</label>
                <select name="pic_id" id="editPICId">
                <option>'.$user.'</option>
                </select>
                </div>';
        return response()->json(['html' => $html]);
    }
```

and the results I get are `[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}]`. how to convert that data into a dropdown list ?

Comment: `$user` is a collection, not a string you can echo in HTML. If you search for the exact error you are getting, you will find many duplicates here on SO.  If you edit your question and include the exact error you are getting, you will get much better help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey need little bit correction. You Can look at this

```
    $complain = new Complain();
    $data = $complain->findData($id);

    $user = User::select('id','name')->where('role_id', '=', 3, 'and')->where('type_id', '=', 3)->get();

$dropdowns = '';
        foreach ($user as $row)
        {
            $dropdowns .= '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
        }
        $html = '<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="ticket">No Ticket:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ticket" id="editTicket" value="' . $data->ticket . '" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="complain">Complain Detail:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="complain" id="editComplain" disabled>' . $data->complain . '
                    </textarea>
                </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="editName" value="' . $data->name . '" disabled>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="kartu">Card Number:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="kartu" id="editKartu" value="' . $data->kartu . '" disabled>
                </div><div class="form-group">
                    <label for="pic_id">Assign To:</label>
                <select name="pic_id" id="editPICId">
                '.$dropdowns.'
                </select>
                </div>';
```